# Proving that the Universe Theory implies Godel-Bernays

Tags: category-theory, set-theory

I'm reading a book on Category Theory, and the authors claim that one gets a model of Godel-Bernays theory by choosing "sets" to be elements of the Universe and "classes" to be subsets of the Universe. I'm not able to prove how this is the case.

To make things clearer, let me state the Universe Axiom and the Godel-Bernays theory.

We say that a set $\mathfrak U$ is a universe if

- $x\in y$ and $ y\in \mathfrak U$, then $x \in \mathfrak U$;
- $I \in \mathfrak U$, and $\forall i \in I, x_i \in \mathfrak U$, then $\cup_{i\in I}x_i \in \mathfrak U$;
- $x \in \mathfrak U$ then $\mathcal P(x) \in \mathfrak U$, where $\mathcal P(x)$ is the power set;
- $x \in \mathfrak U$ and $f:x\to y$ is a surjective function, then $y \in \mathfrak U$;
- $\mathbb N \in \mathfrak U$.

Thus, the Universe Axiom claims that every set belongs to a universe.

The Godel-Bernays theory states that besides sets, we have a primitive called "class" for which we have the axiom:
A class is a set if and only if it belongs to (other) class.

Therefore, I have to prove that for a universe $U$, a subset $S \subset U$ is a set (i.e. $S \in U$) if and only if $S \in V$ where $V \subset U$.

Any ideas on how to prove this?

Comment: There's a typo in your goal: "$S\subset V$" should be "$S\in V$." In Godel-Bernays, sets are exactly classes which are *elements of* other classes.

Comment: Thanks @NoahSchweber, corrected the typo.

Comment: Just to clarify, is your comment supposed to point that the proof is actually a tautology?

Comment: It's pretty trivial, yeah (note that we can set $V=U$).

Comment: Oh, now I understood your comment. We have that every set is a class by axiom. I didn't realize this. I was trying to prove that a set was a class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misstated the universe axiom. As you have phrased it, a universe must be the class of all sets.

For take any set $z$. Define $f : \mathbb{N} \to \{z\}$ by $f(x) = z$. Then $f$ is surjective and $\mathbb{N} \in \mathfrak{U}$, so $\{z\} \in \mathfrak{U}$. Since $z \in \{z\}$, we have $z \in \mathfrak{U}$.

But of course, the class of all sets is not itself a set. Put another way, there is no set of all sets.

The correct way to phrase that part of the axiom is: for any function $f : x \to \mathfrak{U}$, where $x \in \mathfrak{U}$, we have $range(f) \in \mathfrak{U}$.

Once we have a universe, we can produce from it a model of the very strong Morse-Kelley set theory. Every axiom of NBG is a theorem of Morse-Kelley set theory (and in fact implies the consistency of NBG).

In particular, the sort of classes will be $P(\mathfrak{U})$. The relation $\in$ is just the usual $\in$ relation. Note that $P \models \exists Y (X \in Y)$ if and only if $X \in \mathfrak{U}$. We abbreviate $\exists Y (X \in Y)$ as $isSet(X)$. Small variables range over sets, as usual.

> Extensionality: $(\forall x (x \in X \iff x \in Y)) \to X = Y$

Proof: this follows directly from transitivity of $\mathfrak{U}$ plus ambient extensionality.

> Foundation: $A \neq \emptyset \to \exists b \in A \forall c \in A (c \notin b)$

Proof: this follows from transitivity plus ambient foundation.

> Class comprehension schema: all axioms which are universal closures of some statement of the form $\exists Y \forall x (x \in Y \iff \phi(x, W_1, \ldots, W_n))$

Proof: just take $Y = \{x \in \mathfrak{U} \mid P(\mathfrak{U}) \models \phi(x, W_1, \ldots, W_n))\}$. Note: in fact, the second-order class comprehension scheme is satisfied.

> Axiom of pairing: $\exists z \forall w (x \in z \iff w = x \lor w = y)$

Proof: Take $w = \{x, y\}$. To show that $w \in \mathfrak{U}$, we can define $f : \mathbb{N} \to \mathfrak{U}$ by $f(0) = x$, $f(n + 1) = y$. Then $w = range(f)$.

> Limitation of size (I'll write this one in English): $C$ is *not* a set if, and only if, there is some injective $F : V \to C$. Here, $V$ is the necessarily unique class satisfying $\forall x (x \in V)$.

Proof: Suppose that there is some injective $F : V \to C$. That is, we have $F : \mathfrak{U} \to C$. Then if $C \in \mathfrak{U}$, we would have $range(F) \subseteq C \in \mathfrak{U}$ and therefore $range(F) \in \mathfrak{U}$. Since $F$ is injective, we can define $G : range(F) \to \mathfrak{U}$ by setting $G(x)$ to be the unique $y$ such that $F(y) = x$. Then $range(G) = \mathfrak{U} \in \mathfrak{U}$; contradiction.

The converse is a bit trickier. We must use the fact that we can write $\mathfrak{U} = V_\kappa$, where $\kappa$ is a strongly inaccessible cardinal and also the smallest cardinal not in $\mathfrak{U}$. In particular, $\mathfrak{U}$ contains all cardinals smaller than itself.

So suppose we have some $C \subseteq \mathfrak{U}$ but $C \notin \mathfrak{U}$.

First, suppose $|C| < |\mathfrak{U}|$. In that case, we see that $|C| \in \mathfrak{U}$. We can therefore take some bijection $f : |C| \to C$; then $C \in \mathfrak{U}$.

Therefore, since $C \subseteq \mathfrak{U}$ and $|C|$ is not less than $|\mathfrak{U}|$, we must have $|C| = |\mathfrak{U}|$. That is, there is some bijection $F : \mathfrak{U} \to \mathfrak{C}$. This completes the converse.

> Power set: $P(x)$ is a set.

Proof: If $x \in \mathfrak{U}$ then $P(x) \in \mathfrak{U}$.

> Union: $\bigcup x$ is a set.

Proof: if $x \in \mathfrak{U}$ than $\bigcup x \in \mathfrak{U}$.

> Infinity: $\mathbb{N}$ is a set.

Proof: $\mathbb{N} \in \mathfrak{U}$.

Comment: A useful explanation/explication! :)

Comment: NBG doesn’t prove the consistency of NBG. Well, I hope it doesn’t.

Comment: @ZhenLin Not sure how that typo made its way into my post, but thanks for pointing it out.